# Using a value from the .env file and using it in createSecretKey returns error

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, cryptography

I'm basically doing this:

```
const secretKey = crypto.createSecretKey(
    Buffer.from(process.env.SECRET, "hex")
  );
```

And I get the following error: "The value of "key.byteLength" is out of range. It must be > 0. Received 0"

Replacing the process.env.SECRET with the secret itself works.

```
export const createToken = async (id) => {
  const secretKey = crypto.createSecretKey(
    Buffer.from(process.env.SECRET, "hex")
  );

  return await new EncryptJWT({ id })
    .setProtectedHeader({ alg: "dir", enc: "A256GCM" })
    .setIssuedAt()
    .setExpirationTime("14d")
    .encrypt(secretKey);
};
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Where is `createToken` being called from? Can you provide a [mre]?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, your `process.env.SECRET` was probably undefined. Make sure it exists :)